# What should our logo and site design look like?

Tags: discussion, 7-essential-questions

Again, taken from the SO suggested list, but this does seem like a good question.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Interesting. I thought stacks didn't get custom design and logo until they graduated from public beta. At least that is the impression I get from scrolling through the main list of all stack exchange sites.

Comment: I believe the question is meant to solicit ideas so that prior to exiting beta we have an idea. I stole it from the list of "good meta questions" from SE.

Comment: @JasonNichols Ah. Ok. Although my beloved _history.se_ still has default logo and styling; it's been in beta for 3 years. This is not uncommon - Biology and Chemistry have also been in beta for years. Chances are we'll need to dig this post up in 2018. But ah! Let's make hay while the sun shines.

Comment: Do you know if there are any guidelines for the logo/site design or is it pretty much just "anything goes"?

Comment: To my understanding we merely make suggestions, SE has final authority, so the guidelines would be best distilled as "whatever they want". :)

Comment: I hate trying to come up with "branding" for these kinds of econ projects. We could so with generic stock market, dollar sign type stuff, but that would just perpetuate the myth that economics is mostly about money. Alternatively, we could go with some supply and demand inspired branding (or similar), but how to make that look visually exciting? Perhaps a question on the graphic design SE is in order : ).

Comment: added the tag..

Comment: @LateralFractal good news - [Chemistry.SE is graduating](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/484/25). Some sites can hit graduation within much shorter time periods - it's all about building the community

Answer (score 1):

I think the feel of the design is more important than specifics. I'd like an air of weightiness, seriousness, sobriety, intellect, the Enlightenment tradition.

Particular design elements might include some foundational equations, a stylised chart of intersecting supply & demand curves.

Oh, and maybe a picture of David Ricardo stood at the top of Everest in a t-shirt and tennis shoes (hat-tip David Friedman)

Comment: So maybe a serif font, some doric columns... Here's a simple stab in the rough direction that came to mind (not designed by me!): https://0.s3.envato.com/files/29734380/Column%20Logo%20Preview.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I would love the design to incorporate the [Mainline Economists Mural at Universidad Francisco Marroquín](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=903AgvDu-GA).

Answer (score 0):

A illustrated bookshelf of the [most important books in economic thought could work: Wikipedia has a decent list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_important_publications_in_economics) but I suggest confining ourselves to deceased authors.